# Android: What is the default color bitmap of SurfaceView and how to change it?

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, surfaceholder, android-graphics

In my application I have a Translucent `Activity` with `android:windowIsTranslucent` is set to `true`. `Activity` contains a `FrameLayout` to which I programmatically add `SurfaceView`.

By default `SurfaceView` is drawing bitmap, as per the `Activity` background `Theme`, which in my case in `Translucent`, so `SurfaceView` is showing transparent bitmap.

For setting background I used `SurfaceHolder callbacks` in following way:

```
surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) {
                    canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) {
                    canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }
        });
```

In `surfaceCreated()/surfaceChanged()` I am drawing a color.

When the `FrameLayout` containing `SurfaceView` gets resized then `surfaceDestroyed()` callbacks invokes and default **Transparent background shows to user until `surfaceCreated()` invokes again.**

So user sees **Transparent background for a moment.**

My questions is:

1. Is `SurfaceView` uses `Activity` window color to draw default bitmap?
2. Can we change the `color` that `SurfaceView`uses to draw default bitmap?

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but use a TextureView instead of a SurfaceView. SurfaceViews are terrible and cause nothing but problems.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: Thanks for suggestion. But using TextureView instead of SurfaceView is not in my hand.

Comment: You may be able to fix your issue by just assigning a background to the SurfaceView.  By default the Surfaceview actually draws nothing (hence why you "see" the transparent Activity behind it)."  It is though, just a regular View at heart.

Comment: @DeeV:My SurfaceView is playing video content when I set "setBackgroundColor()" to it then video is not visible, but playing and I think it is behind the background. Please help

Comment: Two ideas.  Use either `SurfaceView#setZOrderMediaOverlay()` or `SurfaceView#setZOrderOnTop()`.  Be warned, using this will put the video on top of *everything* means you can't overlay Views over the SurfaceView.  The second idea is to set the background to your color, but then set it to "null" when `onSurfaceCreated()` is called.  Then set the background again when `onSurfaceDestroyed()` is called.

Comment: I'm not setting these as answers since I'm not 100% sure they will fix your problem.

Comment: @DeeV: Thanks for help. I already tried SurfaceView#setZOrderMediaOverlay() or SurfaceView#setZOrderOnTop() approach but as you I need overlay so I ignore this approach. But I am trying second solution. Will update in some time. Thanks

Comment: Bear in mind that SurfaceViews have two parts, the Surface and the View. These are manipulated and updated independently. You can treat the View part like a custom View, but the Surface part is an independent layer that is partially managed by a different process, so there can be visual glitches when things move around. @XaverKapeller: SurfaceViews are actually very useful, but they are widely misunderstood, and the multitude of bad tutorials and examples do not help. See [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for examples of proper use.

Comment: @fadden/@Deev: Attempted to fix by following approach but it didn't help: Setting background to SurfaceView --> Drawing color of Surface in onSurfaceCreated() and setting background to null --> When surface destroyed then setting background to black color. It works well, but as @fadden said there are some glitches while resizing the view that transparent view visible for a moment.

Comment: @Deev/@fadden: 
One query: When surface view gets destroyed than all content that we drawn on it will also gone?

Comment: @SagarTrehan did you find a solution in the end? I'm currently facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @jenzz: No I didn't find any solution yet. I add a hack to fix this issue. Hack is "While loading content in player I add a black background view in z order on top of player view and once onPlaying() callback invokes I set visibility of z order view to GONE". This is DEFINTELY NOT RIGHT SOLUTION I am still struggling. Please let me know as well if found something.